# persist input type "file" on autopostback using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, file-io, input

I have chosen the item from dropdown say item 2 and also browsed 4images, now I'm changing the dropdown selected item from 2 to 4 after the auto postback the browsed images is gone. We need to persist the file after auto postback.

Front end code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
   <input name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple />
</div>
</form>
```

[image]
[image]

Is that possible to persist the selected files using jquery? or we have any security risk to achieve?

Comment: There is nothing to do with your question, but you know there is a `<asp:FileUpload />` control? Then you'll be able to use it in your code.

Comment: On the other hand... Dropdown list is for what? Why user must specify 2 if he'll maybe select finally 3 items to set it to 3 after... Simply shows 3 once he has selected files. Keep it easy yeah?

Comment: @SimonDugré Ya I know, reason to choose the input file is it's easy to show the progress bar and uploading the files with the help of handler using ajax call.

Comment: `<input name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple />` versus `<asp:FileUpload` are none. They at the end output the same if you look at your page source except that ASP can be handles in your code.

Comment: I didn't give you a full picture here, it's just a sample code. For each dropdown selected index change i need to connect database and fetch the settings like donate, share etc.. hiding the buttons based on the selected index change. I'm trying to achieve, if the user chosen the files and they may change the dropdown items but the selected files(any multimedia) should be persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I usually do:

1. Replace your input type="file" by an `<asp:FileUpload />` instead.
2. Then, in your javascript, refer to it using :`var myFUPL = document.getElementById('<%= yourAspFileUploadControl.ClientID %>');` tomake your ajax call (for upload).
3. Then, in your page load, you can access your `<asp:FileUpload />` so you'll be able to handles number of uploaded files there or anything else using yourAspFileUploadControl properties (If I my memory's good, property name is `PostedFiles`. You could also use yourAspFileUploadControl.HasFiles to ensure there are files in it before).

Warning here: You must know that these files are available only from immediate postback. After what, they are removed from FileUpload. As for reason, security purpose.

And to answer explicitly to your question, there is no real way to keep files upon a postback and this is a browser security to be maintained only within primary post and cleaned after that.